# Will the macro `assert` be removed in C++20?

Tags: c++, standards, assert, defensive-programming, c++20

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/contract), `assert` will be used as a C++ attribute.

However, there already exist tons of projects heavily dependent on the macro `assert`, is there any bad effect?

Comment: Are they replacing it with anything or just removing useful functionality?

Comment: There is no problem, because the word `assert` won't be followed by a `(` so it won't invoke the function-style macro.

Comment: @solarflare Nothing is being removed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The new use of `assert` won't cause any problems, because it is not followed by a `(` and therefore the function-style macro `assert(blah)` won't be invoked.

Answer (score 14):

No. The proposal [p0542r5](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2018/p0542r5.html) which introduces C++20 contracts says:

> Note that while `assert(expression)` would expand as a function-like macro with the appropriate header, `assert:` is not a function-like invocation, so does not expand.